# GAE java - Blobstore No file found for

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

```
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When running, i received a warning : No file found for /upload and 404 error.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying the App Engine sample.

Have you followed everything in [App Engine complete sample aplication](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Complete_sample_application)?